# How to connect ImageJ to python?

Tags: python, jython, imagej

I am using Python to design a software, and the image processing is one of the steps. I am using ImageJ to realize this.

Since there is a Jython interpreter within ImageJ, which can be opened within ImageJ software, there must be a way to connect ImageJ to Python and call all the functions within Python.

I wonder how I can do that to finish all the processing in Python rather than open the interpreter in ImageJ?

Comment: Have you looked at opencv2 for python? The step you're performing with imageJ may have a built in function.

Comment: Is it based on openCV? It is not supporting Python34.

Comment: There is a beta opencv3 for python 3.4, otherwise cv2 for 2.7x.

Comment: It seems a lot of people have the problem that they can't find python 3.4 package in /builds/python after they installed 3.0.0 beta version. [Here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/60190/building-opencv-300-beta-windows-python-34/) is one of the questions.

Comment: Justification for working with cv2 and python2.7.x until all that gets worked out.

Answer (score 5):

There is this https://github.com/imagej/imagej.py module which provides an integration between Python and ImageJ.

With it you can easily use ImageJ in Python. Here is a sample script:

```
# Spin up ImageJ.
import imagej
ij = imagej.init('/Applications/Fiji.app')

# Import an image with scikit-image.
import skimage
from skimage import io
# NB: Blood vessel image from: https://www.fi.edu/heart/blood-vessels
img = io.imread('https://www.fi.edu/sites/fi.live.franklinds.webair.com/files/styles/featured_large/public/General_EduRes_Heart_BloodVessels_0.jpg')
import numpy as np
img = np.mean(img, axis=2)

# Invoke ImageJ's Frangi vesselness op.
vessels = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=img.dtype)
import imglyb
ij.op().filter().frangiVesselness(imglyb.to_imglib(vessels), imglyb.to_imglib(img), [1, 1], 20)
```

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT 2018-07-02: There is now an ImageJ python module allowing to start up and use ImageJ from Python. https://github.com/imagej/imagej.py***

> I wonder how I can do that to finish all the processing in Python rather than open the interpreter in ImageJ?

You can write a Jython script with a special header that uses the ImageJ launcher to execute, ensuring all needed libraries are on the classpath:

```
#!/bin/sh
''''exec "$(dirname "$0")"/ImageJ.sh --jython "$0" "$@" # (call again with fiji)'''
```

But this hack only works on POSIX-compatible platforms (i.e., in the case of Windows you would need CYGWIN).

[Fiji](http://fiji.sc/) includes [several example scripts like this](https://github.com/fiji/fiji/tree/b930efb39cc3c537c1a4bcc3bf6313ca78227cb7/bin)—a short and sweet one is [screenshot.py](https://github.com/fiji/fiji/blob/b930efb39cc3c537c1a4bcc3bf6313ca78227cb7/bin/screenshot.py).

Note that Jython *cannot call Python libraries that are backed by native code* (e.g., [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) and [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)). But there is an experimental [CPython script language](https://github.com/scijava/scripting-cpython), which uses the [javabridge](http://pythonhosted.org/javabridge/). It is still immature, and not distributed with [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/) yet. But it allows to call native Python code, including libraries backed by C/C++, from [ImageJ](http://imagej.net/Scripting). The plan is to include this language in Fiji in the future. In the meantime, you can build it yourself and drop the JAR file into ImageJ's `jars` folder. And of course, [feedback](https://groups.google.com/group/scijava) is welcome.

If you develop a more turnkey "Python-centric" solution as you desire, it would be awesome to add a page to the [ImageJ wiki](http://imagej.net/) about it!

Comment: Thank you for the advice! But I wonder how I could import "ij" package in Python? How can I add the package to sys.path?

Answer (score 2):

The [`imglib2-imglyb`](https://github.com/hanslovsky/imglib2-imglyb) project allows to access numpy arrays from Java with [ImgLib2](https://imagej.net/ImgLib2) and vice versa.

Some illustrating examples can be found on [`imglyb-examples`](https://github.com/hanslovsky/imglyb-examples).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the image, you could use the [javabridge](http://pythonhosted.org/javabridge/) connector developed by the Cell Profiler group. It is however notoriously slow.

If you want to design your own binding to ImageJ, you can use [jepp](http://jepp.sourceforge.net/)/[jpype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/) couple, but it will be a lot of work.

The easiest way of doing it would probably be to save your image from ImageJ to an external file and write a macro that would save image, start your custom python processing script, and then re-open the processed image.

Comment: For the last method, you mean process the image offline?

Comment: @chiffa If the javabridge is really "notoriously slow" then I would recommend writing to the CellProfiler developers. The guy who developed it, Lee Kamentsky, is awesome and certainly could help address any bottlenecks.

Comment: @ctrueden: Thanks for the pointer. We've opted for the third solution in our case. I will however shoot an e-mail to Lee Kamentsky if I will be working on Python plugins for ImageJ in the future: the current solution is not very user-friendly.

Comment: @chiffa Thank you for the advice! But I don't think processing offline is what I want. I tried several alternatives, including openCV(not support Python34) and simpleCV(same problem). I feel FIJI is still the one I want to connect with Python.

Comment: Image processing in Python is heavily dependent on C/Fortran routines pulled by numpy/scipy couple, so jython will have trouble pulling them. Regarding the OpenCV, it uses a bunch of meta programming trick from Python 2 and has not been properly ported to Python 3. However, in addition to Python3 incompatibility, it is also a pretty hard work to create GUI with it.