# Using ImageJ Jython in Standalone Python IDE

Tags: python, ide, jython, imagej

I'm wondering if it is possible to call ImageJ from a standalone Python IDE. I want to begin image processing in ImageJ without opening the ImageJ Jython interpreter.  I'm not clear if this is possible given the differences between Python & Jython.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to develop Jython code in a Python IDE, then see chapter 11 of the Jython book: [Using Jython in an IDE](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonIDE.html).

If your goal is to somehow integrate native Python with ImageJ (i.e., not using Jython): it is not a solved problem yet. But perhaps [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29749687/) and [this post on the ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/t/python-scripting/80/3) will give you some ideas on how to start?