# Run ImageJ macro from Python script error not found

Tags: python, subprocess, imagej

**BACKGROUND**

I use Python2.7 and have installed Imagej following the instructions on [www.scivision.dev](https://www.scivision.dev/install-imagej-linux/) without any issues. The app works fine when run from the terminal.

The Java version I use is

```
parovelb@Latitude-E6510:~$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The path to the OpenJDK is set in my `~/.bashrc`

```
# java path
PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java:$PATH
export PATH
```

**QUESTION**

I have trouble running an ImageJ macro from my script in Python2.7. The script calls an ImageJ macro with `subprocess.Popen`. The macro creates a CSV file and writes the results into it. Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
#!/bin/sh -i
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


"""
This program runs an ImageJ macro.
"""


import os
import csv
import sys
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT
from collections import defaultdict


def Connector_Check():
    cmd = ["imagej", "-macro", "luerlocktest.ijm"]
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    (stdoutdata, stderrdata) = process.communicate()
    print 'stdoutdata', stdoutdata

    # read result in row 1, col 2
    with open(" ~/results.csv","rb") as res:
        resReader = csv.reader(res)
        resReader = list(resReader)
        val = resReader[1][2]
    print "Connector check value = ", val


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute connector check
    Connector_Check()
```

If I run the command `imagej -macro luerlocktest.ijm` from the terminal, it works fine but running my script gives me the error:

```
stdoutdata -macro: 1: -macro: imagej: not found

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrapper_imagej.py", line 34, in <module>
    Connector_Check()
  File "wrapper_imagej.py", line 25, in Connector_Check
    with open("/home/parovelb/Desktop/CV/Results.csv","rb") as res:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/parovelb/Desktop/CV/Results.csv'
```

These Q&A below unfortunately does not offer a solution to my problem:

1. [How to connect ImageJ to python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749687/how-to-connect-imagej-to-python)
2. [Using ImageJ Jython in Standalone Python IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385824/using-imagej-jython-in-standalone-python-ide)
3. [Docker image error: “/bin/sh: 1: python: not found”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709075/docker-image-error-bin-sh-1-python-not-found)

Any suggestions on why `imagej: not found`?

**1. UPDATE**

Using `Shell=False` gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrapper_imagej.py", line 34, in <module>
    Connector_Check()
  File "wrapper_imagej.py", line 20, in Connector_Check
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening a shell with `subprocess` doesn't make it execute `.bashrc`, therefore it will never see the modified version of `$PATH`. You might try adding the `shell=False` argument to the `Popen()` call. Other options include adding imagej to your `PATH` in another way, or calling imagej with the full path to the program itself, not requiring the `$PATH` variable at all.

e.g.:

```
cmd = ["/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/imagej", "-macro", "luerlocktest.ijm"]
```

Comment: Introducing the `shell=False` argument into `Popen()` gives me `raise child_exception`

Comment: Thank you @Joost for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I did change the format of the `cmd` and put the path where `ImageJ` is installed in `$HOME/ImageJ/ImageJ`. Also I did use a single command line instead of a list.

Incorrect:

```
cmd = ["imagej", "-macro", "luerlocktest.ijm"]
```

Correct:

```
cmd = ["$HOME/ImageJ/ImageJ -macro luerlocktest.ijm"]
```